# python optparse treat next option as the option argument for the current one when it's missing

Tags: python, optparse

I use optparse to parse the command options for my script.
I have -f and -c options that both require an option argument. But when it's missing, it will treat the next option as option argument for the current option.
e.g.

```
./myScript -f -c
```

this will treat "-c" as option argument for "-f" instead of complaining about option argument missing for "-f" and "-c".
For other normal scenarios, it works fine.

Thank your for any information and solutions!

**update：
solution,by using argparse, this problem can be avoided. it exits with an error complaining about missing argument for options.**

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using `argparse`? I believe `argparse` will do what you want if you use the `action` kwarg; something like this: `parser.add_argument('-f',action='store_true')`

Comment: no any special reasons. I just find optparse in the first place. I just tried argparse, it shows an error when use options that way. thanks!

Comment: **Note**: Using *optparse* is discouraged since python version 2.7. The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module. See [PEP 0389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optparse` is deprecated from python 2.7 on, so you should use the `argparse` module, which has this behaviour built in:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f')
parser.add_argument('-c')

parser.parse_args(['-f', 'f_val', '-c', 'c_val'])   #works as expected
parser.parse_args(['-f', '-c'])                     #errors as expected
```

If you are left with python < 2.7 and the `optparse` module, you can easily do it with a custom check after the parsing stage:

```
parser = OptionParser('usage')
parser.add_option("-f", "--ff", dest="f_value")
parser.add_option("-c", "--cc", dest="c_value")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

if options.f_value == '-c':
    print 'error: -f requires an argument'
    exit(1)
```

Comment: I know it can be solved like this, but I just wonder if I missed something that solve this within optparse module. anyway, thanks

Comment: @nils `optparse` doesn't have this capability. I updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: @nils I would much prefer an upvote instead of thx (it's all about reputation) :)